# How does cv2.projectPoints actually work?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, projection, camera-calibration

I'm trying to write my own implementation of [cv2.projectPoints](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calib#void%20projectPoints(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20rvec,%20InputArray%20tvec,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20imagePoints,%20OutputArray%20jacobian,%20double%20aspectRatio)) just for practice, and my implementation is not behaving as expected.

I'm assuming a pinhole camera with no distortion, so all I'm doing is applying the following equation to all of my planar object points.

[image]

Let's say in some world space (that both a plane and the camera exist in), the plane is 2 units away. So, in world coordinate space, all the points on the plane have `z=2`. However, in the plane's own coordinate space, all the points on the plane have `z=0`. So, the vector `[X Y Z 1]` is actually `[X Y 0 1]` for all of the coordinates I'm trying to project. Let's say I find, in my pose estimation, that the object is translated `-2` in the `z` direction. After multiplying this vector by the found pose, I get the vector...

```
r11X + r12Y  + t1
r21X + r22Y  + t2
r31X + r32Y  + 2
```

But now, the projected point no longer has a `z = 2` because of `r31` and `r32`.

Comment: Afair there is some good explanation of 3d projections in the opengl documentation or the ted book or sth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project points works just as the formula you describe. In the simple case where there is no rotations (Rotational matrix is identity) you will get at the end something like:

```
X + t1
Y + t2
2
```

Which is exactly what you expect. You are using a pose estimation, this means that this simple case will almost never be, since you will have some error always, but should be quite small.... this means that at the end `r31X + r32Y` should lead to something close to 0. If this is not the case, then the pose estimation may have an error. Also, consider that both values can cancel each other as well.

One more thing, once you multiply the WHOLE formula, you will get a 3D vector, and you have to divide the vector by the last component to obtain the 2D projected point.

It would be good, if possible, that you give an example with numbers to understand how much error you actually have, and see if it is due to another thing...